# how to set the delete method in sqlite database correctly?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database called "Users" and a table in that database called "contact". i want to delete a selected contact when I click a button. I want to know how to set the parameters correctly to the delete method. if somebody can gimme an answer with a little example i will be delighted .

my code goes like this

```
private void deleteContact(String name) {

    SQLiteDatabase database=openOrCreateDatabase("Users",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

    int res=database.delete("contact", "name =", name);

    ///


}
```

I call this method when I click that Button. my query is,

"delete from contact where name ='"+name+"';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your datebase table name is `Contact` and `name` is **unique identifier** and name of column you are inserting names is `COLUMN_NAME` then

```
//Delete single item from Db
public void deleteContact(String name){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete("Contact", COLUMN_NAME + " = ?", new String[]{name});
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: @CL. I changed it to `Contact`, and why did you down vote? This is 100% true answer.

Answer (score 0):

private void deleteContact(String name) {

`SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();`

`db.delete("contact","name=?" , new String[]{name});`

`db.close();`

}